# InStr delimiter issue

Tags: ms-access, parsing, vba, delimiter

I'm working on parsing a text file that has lines similar to these:

> Some text (2934418) - KB2933528 - XP x86 
>   Some text - KB2923392 
>   Sometext - KB2933528 - XP x64/2003

(Note: *no empty lines are on the txt file*)

I'm trying to use InStr function to parse the text and only get the KB numbers, but I can't seem to figure out what delimiters to use to do so. Since the "-" are the same characters it keeps returning the same value instead of finding the second "-". Here is the code that I have right now.

`intKbOpen = InStr(1, linedata, "-")
intKbClose = InStr(1, linedata, "-")
intKbDelta = (intKbOpen - intKbClose)
strKb = Mid(linedata, intKbOpen, intKbDelta)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument for InStr is the starting position, so change your second line like this and check for missing second dash:

```
intKbOpen = InStr(1, linedata, "-") + 1
intKbClose = InStr(intKbOpen, linedata, "-")
If intKbClose = 0 Then
   intKbClose = Len(linedata)
   intKbDelta = (intKbClose - intKbOpen) - 1
   strKb = Trim(Mid(linedata, intKbOpen + 1, intKbDelta + 1))
Else
   intKbDelta = (intKbClose - intKbOpen) - 1
   strKb = Trim(Mid(linedata, intKbOpen + 1, intKbDelta))
```

Comment: This works for the first and the last line in the text file. But since there is a second "-" missing on the second line I get a run-time error. because intKbDelta is a negative number

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Had to play with it a bit and add a IF...Then...Else statement but got it to work properly with your help!

Answer (score 3):

Might I suggest using Regular Expressions instead?  If you navigate to Tools ---> References in the VBE, you can check the box next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  This allows you access to the RegExp class which you can use as follows:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim oRegExp As RegExp
    Set oRegExp = New RegExp

    Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim oMatch As Match

    With oRegExp
        .Global = True 'It will find all the matches, not just the first one
        .IgnoreCase = True 'I'm assuming you would still want to capture even if the "kb" is lowercase
        .Multiline = True 'I'm assuming your data may have end-of-line characters in it
        .Pattern = "KB\d+" 'This means, match the letter K, then the letter B, then one or more digits. Ignore everything else.
        Set oMatches = .Execute("Some text (2934418) - KB2933528 - XP x86 Some text - KB2923392 Sometext - KB2933528 - XP x64/2003")
    End With

    For Each oMatch In oMatches
        Debug.Print oMatch
    Next
End Sub
```

Running this function results in the following being printed to the immediate window in VBA:

```
KB2933528
KB2923392
KB2933528
```

Comment: Thank you, but this part is only a small part of the large parsing module I'm writing and would like to keep the format similar to the rest of the text that is being parsed. That's why I'm still using the InStr function

Comment: Ok, good luck! If you get the chance, you might look into [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), as they provide a lot of power to specify exactly what you want.  Perhaps they could help you in future projects :)

Answer (score 1):

Some notes, not suitable for SQL, other than as a UDF, which will not be available outside MS Access.

```
x1 = "Some text (2934418) - KB2933528 - XP x86"
x2 = "Some Text - KB2923392"
x3 = "Sometext - KB2933528 - XP x64/2003"

astrX = Split(x1, "-") '' And so on

For i = 0 To UBound(astrX)
    ''# is any number
    If astrX(i) Like "*KB###*" Then 
        sKB = astrX(i)
    End If
Next

Debug.Print sKB
```